# Prototype js get element with certain value

Tags: dom, screen-scraping, prototypejs

I am scraping some data and I want to get the the value of an element after a specific tag with value.

It's a bold tag with value 'Types:'.

```
<b>Types:</b>
```

Once I get to that element I can use Prototype's Element.next() to get the data I want.

How exactly do I do this?
I have been fiddling with $$ but can't seem to get it right..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the first b element with value "Types:":

```
$$('b').find(function(n){return n.innerHTML=="Types:"})
```